# How data type value is stored in memory in C

Tags: c, stack

i'm actually new to C and i tried this while debugging a c program using gdb.

Here is my Program

```
int main(){
int a = 4;
int b = 8;
}
```

Then i used Gdb to debug the program, step through 2 lines of assembly code which set the value for `a` and `b`

```
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x4
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x8
```

The value of rbp is `0x7fffffffde70`
Since the `int` data type has 4 bytes and the stack grows from high value address to low value address,the address of `a` must be `0x7fffffffde70 - 0x4` = `0x7fffffffde6c` and the address of `b` must be `0x7fffffffde70 - 8` = `0x7fffffffde68` which returned `4` and `8` as expected.
But when i print the value at the address `0x7fffffffde6b 0x7fffffffde6a 0x7fffffffde69` it print `0x00000400 0x00040000 0x04000000` which seems so weird since `a` has value `4` which could be stored by using the first byte only and those 3 addresses should contain `0x0` isn't it?

Comment: So to print the full value of `a` you should print the four addresses ending with `0x6c`, `0x6d`, `0x6e` and `0x6f`. On a little-[endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system like x86 they should have `4`, `0`, `0` and `0` respectively. Any address outside of that range will have indeterminate values. Also, print them as *bytes* not 32-bit `int` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is 32 bits in your C implementation. Using hexadecimal to show all 32 bits used to represent the values, 4 is represented with 00000004<sub>16</sub> and 8 is represented with 00000008<sub>16</sub>.

When an integer value is stored in memory, your C implementation stores it with the lowwest-value byte first, then the next lowest-value byte, then the next lowest, and so on. So, if 00000004<sub>16</sub> is stored starting at address 7fffffffde6c<sub>16</sub> and 00000008<sub>16</sub> is stored at 7fffffffde68<sub>16</sub>, then the memory contents are:

| Address | Contents |
| --- | --- |
| 7fffffffde68<sub>16</sub> | 08<sub>16</sub> |
| 7fffffffde69<sub>16</sub> | 00<sub>16</sub> |
| 7fffffffde6a<sub>16</sub> | 00<sub>16</sub> |
| 7fffffffde6b<sub>16</sub> | 00<sub>16</sub> |
| 7fffffffde6c<sub>16</sub> | 04<sub>16</sub> |
| 7fffffffde6d<sub>16</sub> | 00<sub>16</sub> |
| 7fffffffde6e<sub>16</sub> | 00<sub>16</sub> |
| 7fffffffde6f<sub>16</sub> | 00<sub>16</sub> |

When you ask the debugger to print a 32-bit integer from the address 7fffffffde6b<sub>16</sub>, it loads four bytes starting from that address, getting 00<sub>16</sub>, 04<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>. Since the lowest-value byte is stored first, these form the integer 00000400<sub>16</sub>.

Similarly, printing a 32-bit integer from 7fffffffde6a<sub>16</sub> yields the bytes 00<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>, 04<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>, making 00040000<sub>16</sub>, and printing a 32-bit integer from 7fffffffde69<sub>16</sub> yields the bytes 00<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>, 04<sub>16</sub>, making 04000000<sub>16</sub>.

Note that, while the stack grows “downward” (toward lower addresses) in your system, this applies to how function call stack frames are ordered and how individual “push” and “pop” processor instructions behave. It does not control how a compiler arranges variables within a stack frame. The order in which a compiler places variables within a frame is not required to match the order in which they are declared. Especially when you turn on optimization and the variables have different types, the compiler may put the variables in different orders.

Also, while the debugger may be able to load a 32-bit integer from any address, your system may have alignment rules that require 32-bit integers to be located at multiples of four bytes in ordinary situations. Do not expect a regular program, rather than the debugger, to be able to load a 32-bit integer from unaligned addresses without generating a program fault that interrupts execution.